# Error when sharing namespace among files using (in-ns)

Tags: clojure, namespaces, ring

I am sharing a namespace among all my ring routes in order to keep each route in its own file, so I have a file `routes/core.clj` that contains:

```
(ns test-proxy.routes.core)
;; Some utility functions
```

Then I start each route handler file like this:

```
(in-ns 'test-proxy.routes.core)
;; rest of the code
```

When I start the server, it works perfectly.

But when I make a change in any of the files and reload the page in the browser, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Found lib name 'test-proxy.routes.core' 
containing period with prefix 'quote'.  lib names inside prefix lists 
must not contain periods
```

If I restart the server manually (`lein ring server`), all works as expected again, but as soon as I make another change in the code base, it fails with the same error. It definitely looks related to the way I'm using namespaces, but what gets me is that it works without a problem when I restart the server.

If I unquote the namespace to `(in-ns test-proxy.routes.core)` like the error seems to suggest, the server doesn't even start:

```
Syntax error (ClassNotFoundException) compiling at (diplomat/routes/docs.clj:1:1).
test-proxy.routes.core
```

Answer (score 1):

`in-ns` is only meant to be used when at the REPL.

It is fine to divide up your functions any way you want.  Just use the fully-qualified name like `some.ns.of.mine/my-fn` when you reference the function from any other namespace.

Of course, you can always use a namespace alias like:

```
(ns some.other.ns.of.mine 
  (:require [some.ns.of.mine :as snom]))   ; define namespace alias

....

  (snom/my-fn ...)   ; invoke the fn
```

Be sure to also see [How to ns](https://stuartsierra.com/2016/08/27/how-to-ns)

Comment: I'd sorta quibble with your thesis here: `in-ns` is used by some libraries for exactly this purpose, to split a namespace across multiple files. Most notable, of course, is clojure.core itself, but we know that is not a good exemplar for user code to follow. I agree it's a bad idea to do as the question tries to do, but I wouldn't go so far as to say `ns` isn't meant for it, since that is its very first use!

Comment: Thanks for the link, @alan-thompson I'll read it. But even if it's not idiomatic to use, it works well when the program is executed. It's (I believe) when `lein-ring` causes auto-reload that it throws that error...and I don't understand why.

Comment: When you use `in-ns`, you are essentially lying about what namespace is in the file. Thus, the auto-reload capability of `lein-ring` gets confused, and then you get errors. So, don't do that!